# Repository bean not getting instantiated

Tags: java, spring

I have this repository interface:

```
public interface ScoreCardRepository extends CrudRepository<ScoreCard, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT SUM(SCORE) FROM SCORE_CARD WHERE USER_ID = :userId", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer getTotalScoreForUser(Long userId);
}
```

and this controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gamification")
public class GamificationController {

    private final LeaderBoardServiceImpl leaderBoardService;

    private final GameServiceImpl gameService;

    @Autowired
    public GamificationController(GameServiceImpl gameService, LeaderBoardServiceImpl leaderBoardService){
        this.gameService = gameService;
        this.leaderBoardService = leaderBoardService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/retrieve-stats")
    ResponseEntity<GameStats> getUserStats(@RequestParam("user") String userId){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(gameService.retrieveStatsForUser(Long.parseLong(userId)));
    }

}
```

Now, when I call the `/retrieve-stats` and we go inside `gameService.retrieveStatsForUser` I get a null pointer exception

```
@Service
public class GameServiceImpl implements GameService {

    private final ScoreCardRepository scoreCardRepository;

    private final BadgeCardRepository badgeCardRepository;

    @Autowired
    public GameServiceImpl(ScoreCardRepository scoreCardRepository, BadgeCardRepository badgeCardRepository) {
        this.scoreCardRepository = scoreCardRepository;
        this.badgeCardRepository = badgeCardRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public GameStats retrieveStatsForUser(Long userId) {
        List<BadgeCard> badgeCardList = badgeCardRepository.findByUserIdOrderByBadgeTimestampDesc(userId);
--->>>  int totalScore = scoreCardRepository.getTotalScoreForUser(userId); //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
        GameStats gameStats = new GameStats(userId, totalScore,
                badgeCardList.stream().map(BadgeCard::getBadge).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return gameStats;
    }
}
```

Does this mean that the `scoreCardRepository` bean doesn't get instantiated? That should happen in the @Autowired `GamificationserviceImpl` constructor right? the `badgeCardRepository` gets instantiated fine. What's happening?

Comment: You might be interested in reading [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest another cause:

```
Integer getTotalScoreForUser(Long userId);
```

This method can return in **Integer** of `null` which causes a NPE during auto-boxing to primitive datatype **int** at

```
int totalScore = scoreCardRepository.getTotalScoreForUser(userId);
```